# .exe.manifest did not succeed

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment, activation

Sorry for my lack of knowledge about application deployment, but I have an issue after deploying my application on a network drive - I get the following error; here is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log:

> Activation of Y:\DataBase\MSR-SEK\LessonsLearnt\Application Files\LessonsLearntAlert_1_0_0_2\LessonsLearntAlert.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
>   + Downloading file:///Y:/DataBase/MSR-SEK/LessonsLearnt/Application Files/LessonsLearntAlert_1_0_0_2/Application Files/LessonsLearntAlert_1_0_0_2/LessonsLearntAlert.exe.manifest did not succeed.
>   + Could not find a part of the path 'Y:\DataBase\MSR-SEK\LessonsLearnt\Application Files\LessonsLearntAlert_1_0_0_2\Application Files\LessonsLearntAlert_1_0_0_2\LessonsLearntAlert.exe.manifest'.
>   + Could not find a part of the path 'Y:\DataBase\MSR-SEK\LessonsLearnt\Application Files\LessonsLearntAlert_1_0_0_2\Application Files\LessonsLearntAlert_1_0_0_2\LessonsLearntAlert.exe.manifest'.
>   + Could not find a part of the path 'Y:\DataBase\MSR-SEK\LessonsLearnt\Application Files\LessonsLearntAlert_1_0_0_2\Application Files\LessonsLearntAlert_1_0_0_2\LessonsLearntAlert.exe.manifest'.

Please note that the application is deployed for online run from network drive. There is no issue on my local machine issue to run the application from network drive, but the other PCs on the network have the above issue.

I have no idea why I get this error:

> Could not find a part of the path 'Y:\DataBase\MSR-SEK\LessonsLearnt\Application Files\LessonsLearntAlert_1_0_0_2\Application Files\LessonsLearntAlert_1_0_0_2\LessonsLearntAlert.exe.manifest'

Appreciate if anyone could help and look into the issue. Thanks

Comment: Edits: Thank you @marc_s for the edits & correction. The error for  **'Could not find a part of the path'** has been fixed by providing the correct path in "Install Mode and Settings" tab under Application Updates... panel, however the issue still persists for the other PCs on network. Now there is no error message but the funny thing is that the application is doing nothing (no error/no run) on other network machines. On local machine its doing well for new versions and setup etc. Its a strange behavior for me :)

Comment: **Solution** decryption of connectionString tag in **app.config**  solved the problem. Encrypting of connection string tag is good for security reason to hide the connection string and database password while deploying the application manifest on network share folder. After decryption, the connection string in .config.deply file is visible now so I need to transfer the connection string to all the windows forms.

Comment: **SOLVED** Thanks